# how will one design map with all the zoom in/out features?

Tags: dictionary

Hi
If one wants to design a map with zoom features..how should I start?Which web applications best support these features of laltitude , division of area etc in graphics ...Kindly provide the APIs if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some good experience with open layers: http://openlayers.org/

More Map APIs you might find here: http://www.webappers.com/category/components/maps/